# Difference Between Windows Native OpenSSH and openssh-portable(Win32-OpenSSH)

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I setup two SSH servers on two Window 10 machine. One uses the native OpenSSH server of Windows 10, and the other uses the openssh 7.7.2.1 installed via Chocolatey. The configurations of the sshd are exactly the same.

When I connect to them via iTerm2 from my MAC. The native OpenSSH sever adjusts to the color theme of iTerm2 and the openssh server render the background black (see picture). I was wondering what is the cause for this?

[image]

Comment: Check the value of the TERM environment variable on the remote system. The different ssh programs may be setting different TERM values for the session.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. the TERM variables on both machine are set to xterm-256color